# Neo4j - Find node by ID - How to get the ID for querying?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, graph-databases

I want to be able to to find a specific node by it's ID for performance reasons (IDs are more efficient than indexes)

In order to execute the following example:

```
MATCH (s)
WHERE ID(s) = 65110
RETURN s
```

I will need the ID of the node (65110 in this case)

But how to I get it? Since the ID is auto-generated, It's impossible to find the ID without querying the graph, which kind of defeats the purpose since I will already have the node.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you don't know why you want to look up by id, then don't. Use indexed properties and labels as +Mikesname said.

Comment: I know why I wanted to lookup by ID - performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: use an indexed property for lookups unless you absolutely need to optimise and can measure the difference.

Typically you use an index lookup as an *entry point* to the graph, that is, to obtain the node that provides the start of an edge traversal. While the pointer-like nature of Neo4j node IDs means they are theoretically faster, index lookups are also very efficient so you should not discount them on performance grounds unless you are sure it will make a measurable difference.

You should also consider that **Neo4j node IDs are not stable**. If you delete a node it is possible for the same ID to be re-used in future. For this reason they should really be considered an internal implementation detail and not one that should be relied on as part of your application's external interface.

That said, I have an application that stores Neo4j IDs in a Solr index for looking up nodes in bulk, but this index is considered volatile and the nodes also contain an indexed, application-generated UUID property (with a unique constraint) that serves as their main "primary key".

Further reading and discussion: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/258